# Rx subscribe FromEvents merge all

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Say I have a set of stock symbols:

```
StockTicker stockTicker = 
  new StockTicker("MSFT", "APPL", "YHOO", "GOOG");
stockTicker.OnPriceChanged += (sender, args ) => 
{
  Console.WriteLine(
    "{0}: Price - {1}  Volume - {2}", 
    args.StockSymbol, args.Price, args.Volume);
};
```

I can subscribe to the events and get it as a `hot IObservable`:

```
IObservable<PriceChangedEventArgs> priceChangedObservable = 
  Observable.FromEventPattern<PriceChangedEventArgs>(
    eventHandler => stockTicker.OnPriceChanged += eventHandler,
    eventHandler => stockTicker.OnPriceChanged -= eventHandler )
      .Select( eventPattern => eventPattern.EventArgs );

priceChangedObservable.Subscribe(args => Console.WriteLine( 
  "{0}: Price - {1}  Volume - {2}", 
    args.StockSymbol, args.Price, args.Volume ) );
```

This prints the quote for each symbol as a new quote comes in: In sequence each event is a single qute `YHOO 25.33, MSFT 127, AAPL 175, GOOG 1126` etc.

How do I modify the code above so that each "quote" is a combination of all the current quotes of each individual quote? `(YHOO 25.33, MSFT 127, GOOG 1126, AAPL 175)`. A "quote" is now the state of the last quote seen from all of them, served as one "quote".

I see that Rx has a `Zip` operator, but the semantics of that appear to need `n` `IObservables` to zip. Here there are multiple quotes coming through the same `IObservable`?

So the `Console.WriteLine` would print all n-quotes subscribed to as a single point-event (and only print when all of them have a value)

Answer (score 3):

If these are random events arriving in any order and you are only interested in the latest value at any time, then perhaps you want a dictionary that is kept updated using the [`Scan`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) operator:

```
source
    /* keep track of the latest value for each symbol */
    .Scan(new Dictionary<string, decimal>(), (a, b) => a[b.StockSymbol] = b.Price)

    /* example logic to wait until they all have values */
    .Where(dict => stockTicker.StockSymbols.All(dict.ContainsKey))

    .Subscribe(dict => { ... });
```

---

If the number of events you want to buffer remains constant and you know the source is cycling between the events, the [`Buffer`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) operator might work for you:

```
source
    /* burst values periodically */
    .Buffer(count)

    .Subscribe(list => { ... })
```

Comment: They don't arrive in any order these are stock quotes they are random events.

Comment: @Ivan Please see if the update addresses your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very convinient to think about everything in terms of data pipes.
There is a great library to [DynamicData](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData) which intoduce the concept of reactive collections.

I assume `PriceChangedEventArgs.StockSymbol` is `string`

```
var cache = new SourceCache<PriceChangedEventArgs,string>(x => x.StockSymbol);
cache.PopulateFrom(priceChangedObservable);
```

now you can monitor all the items with

```
cache.Connect()
  .Select(cache.Items)
  .Subscribe({...});
```

The simple solution is to use `Scan`, but with reactive collections you can apply transformations like concat, sort, filter etc